# Highgui cannot be resolved, what is its replacement in the new version of opencv?

Tags: java, opencv, face-detection

I have this piece of code which I was trying to run it and test it, but unfortunately I couldn't:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;
import org.opencv.videoio.VideoCapture;

public class FaceDetection extends javax.swing.JFrame {
///

    private DaemonThread myThread = null;
    int count = 0;
    VideoCapture webSource = null;
    Mat frame = new Mat();
    MatOfByte mem = new MatOfByte();
    CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(FaceDetection.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath().substring(1));
    MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
///    

    class DaemonThread implements Runnable {

        protected volatile boolean runnable = false;

        public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
                while (runnable) {
                    if (webSource.grab()) {
                        try {
                            webSource.retrieve(frame);
                            Graphics g = jPanel1.getGraphics();
                            faceDetector.detectMultiScale(frame, faceDetections);
                            for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
                               // System.out.println("ttt");
                                Imgproc.rectangle(frame, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                                        new Scalar(0, 255,0));
                            }
                            Highgui.imencode(".bmp", frame, mem);
                            Image im = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(mem.toArray()));
                            BufferedImage buff = (BufferedImage) im;
                            if (g.drawImage(buff, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()-150 , 0, 0, buff.getWidth(), buff.getHeight(), null)) {
                                if (runnable == false) {
                                    System.out.println("Paused ..... ");
                                    this.wait();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            System.out.println("Error");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

/////////
    /**
     * Creates new form FaceDetection
     */
    public FaceDetection() {
        initComponents();
        System.out.println(FaceDetection.class.getResource("haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath().substring(1));
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 376, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jButton1.setText("Start");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Pause");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(255, 255, 255)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(86, 86, 86)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addContainerGap(258, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed
        myThread.runnable = false;            // stop thread
        jButton2.setEnabled(false);   // activate start button 
        jButton1.setEnabled(true);     // deactivate stop button

        webSource.release();  // stop caturing fron cam


    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed

        webSource = new VideoCapture(0); // video capture from default cam
        myThread = new DaemonThread(); //create object of threat class
        Thread t = new Thread(myThread);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        myThread.runnable = true;
        t.start();                 //start thrad
        jButton1.setEnabled(false);  // deactivate start button
        jButton2.setEnabled(true);  //  activate stop button


    }//GEN-LAST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FaceDetection.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FaceDetection.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FaceDetection.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FaceDetection.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new FaceDetection().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

I got from the internet and I was modifying some of its parts

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Highgui cannot be resolved
```

Comment: `ImgCodecs.imencode`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked **Miki**

Answer (score 0):

first i am not aware about the new version of opencv and have no experience with java. But try putting lib files  from "\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin" into your application folder(where your compiled exe is) and rebuilding your application. This is for windows os and do find a work around if you are working on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

`import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
Imgcodecs.imencode(".bmp", frame, mem);`

instead of using HighGUI you can use imgcodecs for opencv >3.0.